# Change wallpaper via ssh

Tags: ssh, desktop-background, gconf

I have a server running `12.04 32bit`.

I would like to change the wallpaper via an `ssh` connection.

I tried the following command, but it didn't change the wallpaper. The command works if I am on the server (physically sat down with a keyboard and monitor connected), but not via an `ssh` connection.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///tmp/ozvsk.jpg"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: are you getting any particular error?  What is the full ssh command that you are using?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try the following:

```
ssh user@remotehost
```

Once you are logged in the remote host you need to export the "Display" so you can search it with this.

```
env | grep 'DISPLAY'
```

The result is:

```
DISPLAY=:0
```

Now you can export the DISPLAY.

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Then you can set the background.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///tmp/ozvsk.jpg"
```

Cheers.

Comment: `env | grep 'DISPLAY'` is empty for me. When I `export DISPLAY=:0` and execute `gsettings ...` nothing happens

Comment: if you want to do ssh on localhost, try this:
ssh -X user@127.0.0.1, then you can search the Display with
env | grep 'DISPLAY' (eg: DISPLAY=localhost:10.0).
Finally use the gsettings:
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background picture-uri "file:///home/user/wallpaper.jpg".
Hope this will be helpful.